# is there any way to join multiple tables and perform GROUP BY and COUNT on one of the fields to be returned using MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, count

Sample tables

```
 T1:   pro_id(pk)|name       T2: cus_id (pk)|name|gender    T3: id (pk) | pro_id (FK)|cus_id (FK)
      ---------------           -------------------          ---------------------------------
            p1|Fearless               1  |James|Male              1  |  p1        |  1
            p2|fanta                  2  |Kaddy|Female            2  |  p3        |  1
            p3|soul mate              3  |Bob  |Null              3  |  p1        |  2
```

I need to return all the *pro_id*, *Gender* and *count of gender* (how many male or female) that ordered a particular product.
Bellow is the expected result;

```
pro_id|Gender|Gender_count
--------------------------
 p1   |None  | 5
 p1   |Male  | 10
 p1   |Female| 8
 p2   |None  | 2
 p2   |Male  | 6
 p2   |Female| 15
 P3   |None  | 1
 .
 .
```

I tried the code below but didn't yield the expected result

```
SELECT T3.pro_id, T2.gender, (select count(*) from T3 where T3.cus_id = T2.cus_id) as count FROM T2, T3
```

I also tried the sample code below with a couple of others but to no avail

```
SELECT T1.pro_id, T2.gender, count(T2.gender)
FROM T1
JOIN T3 ON T1.pro_id = T3.pro_id
JOIN T2 ON T2.cus_id = T3.cus_id
GROUP BY T2.gender
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the right idea, but you're missing the `pro_id` in the `group by` clause. You are also referring to the table alias `p` which doesn't exist in the `group by` clause - you probably meant to refer to `T2.gender`, like you did in the `select` list.

```sql
SELECT T1.pro_id, T2.gender, count(T2.gender)
FROM T1
JOIN T3 ON T1.pro_id = T3.pro_id
JOIN T2 ON T2.cus_id = T3.cus_id
GROUP BY T1.pro_id, T2.gender
```

Comment: oh thank you its a typo, its suppose to be `T2.gender` as you rightly mentioned. Your solution worked well but why do we need to `group by` two columns instead of one? @Mureinik

Comment: @DaveK. You need to group by the columns you want to show unique results for. In your case, you want to show a count per pro_id and gender combination, so you should have them both in the `group by` clause.